# Pi won't boot after i installed upstart

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bootloader, upstart

So, here is my problem: I installed upstart on my raspbian (jessie) yesterday. After i tried to reboot the system, the boot loader didn't load any further.

The problem is, that the sd card is in my pi which is unreachable anymore since i installed the pi in my robot (and i would have to break the body to get to the sd card). My question now is, is it possible to get into the rescue menu? If not, are there any other viable options?

Answer (score -2):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088537/rasperry-pi-wont-boot-any-more-after-installing-upstart

I followed these instructions and was able to remove upstart and get back to a working system.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! In keeping with our [policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/19949), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.